# Django Very simple navigation bar, my form does not show up after {% extend "base.html" %}

Tags: python, django, navigation

I am writing a very simple navigation bar. For example I have my login view down below. When I open the login page I can see my the results of my base.html but for some reason I can not see the results of my login.html, meaning I cant see the form I wrote only the top links bar.

**view.py -- login view**

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserLoginForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            m = UserLogin.objects.get(user_name=request.POST['user_name'])
            if m.password == request.POST['password']:
                request.session['member_id'] = m.id
                return  HttpResponseRedirect('/game')
            else:
                c = {'form': form,
                     'error_message': "Your username and password didn't match."}
                c.update(csrf(request))
                return render_to_respons('game/login.html', c)
    else:
        form = UserLoginForm()
    c = {'form': form}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('game/login.html', c)
```

**base.html**

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="/game">Home</a>
    <a href="/game/upload">Upload</a>
    <a href="/game/registration">Register</a>
    <a href="/game/login">Login</a>
</div>
```

**login.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
<form action="/game/login/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<table border='0'>
<div class="fieldWrapper"><tr><td>
        {{ form.user_name.errors }}</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>
        <label for="id_user_name">User Name:</label></td><td>
        {{ form.user_name }}</td></tr>
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper"><tr><td>
        {{ form.password.errors }}</td><td></td><tr><td>
        <label for="id_password">Password:</label></td><td>
        {{ form.password }}</td></tr>
    </div>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `blocks` to use template inheritance. For example, change your base.html to:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="/game">Home</a>
    <a href="/game/upload">Upload</a>
    <a href="/game/registration">Register</a>
    <a href="/game/login">Login</a>
</div>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

then place your login code into the content block:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
...login.html content goes here
{% endblock %}
```

Check out the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#templatesinh) for more detail.

Comment: Block declarations don't have to be at the bottom. They are more than placeholders as they can also contain default markup when you omit them in the child templates. You should really read the (excellent) documentation.